# GWT SuperDevMode throws this: Multiple fragment 0 sourcemaps found. Too many permutations

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5, source-maps

I am using SuperDevMode with Chrome and it worked fine until suddently the sourcemaps stopped showing in Chrome.
And CodeServer throws the following exception: `Multiple fragment 0 sourcemaps found. Too many permutations.`

During compilation it shows:

```
Compiling 5 permutations
  Compiling permutation 0...
  Source Maps Enabled
  Compiling permutation 1...
  Source Maps Enabled
  Compiling permutation 2...
  Source Maps Enabled
  Compiling permutation 3...
  Source Maps Enabled
  Compiling permutation 4...
  Source Maps Enabled
Compile of permutations succeeded
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to reduce the permutations count by modifying your user agent information. You would need 1 or 2 ( firefox or chrome in dev mode ).

Comment: Well normally SuperDevMode chooses only one. At the start of the CodeServer it says: `workDir: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-1478640388313774510.tmp
binding: user.agent=safari
binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
binding: locale=en`

Answer (score 4):

By default GWT compiles 6 basic permutations, one for each category of browser.

- Firefox, all versions
- All Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome, Android Browser, etc)
- IE6 and IE7
- IE8
- IE9 (and IE10)
- Opera

There is a reported issue about that: [Issue 7458: Super Dev Mode shouldn't compile 6 permutations when user.agent is missing](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7458)

Suggested workaround from the issue description:

> is to restrict the browser permutations in the gwt.xml file. For example, if you are using Chrome or Safari:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
```

Also if you're using Sencha GXT I also recommend look through the following article: [Using the GWT Compiler for Better Builds](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-the-gwt-compiler-for-better-builds)

According to the article I also added following line to my gwt.xml:

```
<collapse-all-properties />
```

So finaly my config for SuperDev mode is the following:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>
<collapse-all-properties />
```

As result GWT compiles only one permutation:

```
binding: user.agent=safari
binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
binding: locale=en
Compiling module com.mycompany.Main
...
Compiling 1 permutation
  Compiling permutation 0...
  Source Maps Enabled
Compile of permutations succeeded
```

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is that GXT only obeys gxt.user.agent and not user.agent, so even if you have user.agent set, it compiles every user.agent supported in the config. If, instead, you visit the code server and include the parameter "gxt.user.agent=chrome" (for example), it will only compile the permutations for that agent. If you have your configuration set to have one permutation for that agent, your problem should be solved.

Comment: Works for me! Also could confirm that <collapse-all-properties /> is required to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you add locales but do not add the `en` locale explicitly and/or don't "remove" the `default` locale **and** you didn't *Dev Mode Off* before loading the page in your browser.

For instance, in my module, I had:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="fr"/>
```

With this setting, there are 2 locales: `fr` and `default` (but the `default` locale is no longer used, as I override the fallback to `fr`).

When launching SuperDevMode, it compiles 2 permutations (probably because it forces the `locale` to `en` but doesn't actually checks whether such a locale exists in the module).

I had previously launched the app and turned *Dev Mode On*, but then stopped and restarted the SuperDevMode. When I refresh the page in Chrome, because it's still *in dev mode* (the state is stored in `localStorage`), it loads the script from SuperDevMode and tries to load the source maps right away, and this fails as the SuperDevMode compiled 2 permutations and not just one.
Clicking *Dev Mode On* and *Compile* forces the SuperDevMode to recompile using the properties from the browser environment (`locale=fr` here, as it's the fallback). It thus compiles a single permutation and source maps work again.

In my specific case, I needed a single permutation; all I had to do was to add `<set-property name="locale" value="fr"/>`.

You must be in a similar situation.

I'm sorry that's all the information I can share. Nothing authoritative.

Comment: Actually I did not change anything to the locales except for adding for Messages with their respective properties files. But it got fixed by itself somehow, so I'll try what you say "go to SDM Off then back On the next time it happens to me.

Comment: This worked for me. Reducing the number of possible agents to even ONE did not.